# MongoDB / Mongoose find number of results before you

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's  say I have a mongoose model with the name "points". I'm ordering it with the column name "points". And finding out my document by passing in my userid to the document column name userid.

How can I be able to find out certain information such as "there are xx persons better than you?"

In this case how many documents that have higher points than you?

How many searches does it need to "loop" through until the match of your document is there?

Answer (score 6):

Query for the user's points and then query for the count of users with points higher than that.

```
Points.findOne({userId: userId}, (err, doc) => {
    Points.count({points: {$gt: doc.points}}, (err, count) => {
        // do something with count...
    });
});
```

For scalable performance, you'd want to separately index `userId` and `points`. In your schema:

```
userId: {type: ObjectId, index: true},
points: {type: Number, index: true},
...
```

This should be faster than any map-reduce solution.

Comment: You should probably make sure that your collection is indexed on the `points` property by running a command like this
`db.points.createIndex({points: 1})` to avoid the `count` running slow with larger collections

Comment: @Gaafar Yep, same with `userId`. I'll add that info, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is already solved in another answer 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/22902445/6386175](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898757/get-documents-placement-in-collection-based-on-sort-order/22902445#22902445)

You can use [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) for small dataset or better, maintain a separate ordered collection.

If you want to use mongoose, the Model object has [`Model.mapReduce`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce) method too with the same syntax.

Comment: Could you show me mapreduce or maintain a separate ordered one !

Comment: In the example I linked you can see an detailed solution to your problem. Replace "score" with "points"... and you can get the current position of the user in the ranking.

Comment: Yes. I just updated the answer with the mongoose api reference of `Model.mapReduce`.